# Leaflet.js Circle Click Event Handler

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to get a circle click event to update 'name' id, but am having trouble getting the sites the "name" variable to change once I click one of the circles. The error that I am getting says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined", which is coming from this line: 
var name = e.sites[i].names;

```js
// Define variables for our base layers
var streetmap = L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
  attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>",
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: "mapbox.streets",
  accessToken: "pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
});

// satellite map background tile layer
var satellitemap =  L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
    attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>",
    maxZoom: 15,
    id: "mapbox.satellite",
    accessToken: "pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
});

var darkmap = L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
  attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>",
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: "mapbox.dark",
  accessToken: "pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
});

// Initialize all of the LayerGroups to be used
var layers = {
  CREEK_SITES: new L.LayerGroup()
};

// Create the map with layers
var map = L.map("map", {
  center: [44.953457, -93.502959],
  zoom: 11,
  layers: [
    layers.CREEK_SITES
  ]
});

// Add 'darkmap' tile layer to the map as default
darkmap.addTo(map);


// Create an overlay object
var overlayMaps = {
  "Stream Level": layers.CREEK_SITES
};

var baseMaps = {
  "Street Map": streetmap,
  "Dark Map": darkmap
};


L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

 
// CREEK SITES LAYER
// =================================================================================================

var sites = [{
  names: "CPA01",
  location: [44.964088, -93.672554],
  subwatershed: "Painters Creek"
},
{
  names: "CMH04",
  location: [44.901323, -93.332248],
  subwatershed: "Minnehaha Creek"
},
{
  names: "CMH24",
  location: [44.915574, -93.242167],
  subwatershed: "Minnehaha Creek"
}
];

//Change the size and color of circular markers here
  for (var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
   circle = new L.circle(sites[i].location, 200, {
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        color: "orange",
        fillColor: "blue"
      }).addTo(layers.CREEK_SITES).on("click", circleClick);
      
        function circleClick(e) {
          var name = e.sites[i].names;
          return document.getElementById('name').innerHTML=name;
        }
    }



    var sites = [{
      names: "CPA01",
      location: [44.964088, -93.672554],
      subwatershed: "Painters Creek"
    },
    {
      names: "CMH04",
      location: [44.901323, -93.332248],
      subwatershed: "Minnehaha Creek"
    },
    {
      names: "CMH24",
      location: [44.915574, -93.242167],
      subwatershed: "Minnehaha Creek"
    }
    ];


    for (var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
            circle = new L.circle(sites[i].location, 200, {
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            color: "orange",
            fillColor: "blue"
          }).addTo(layers.CREEK_SITES).on("click", circleClick);
          
            function circleClick(e) {
              var name = e.sites[i].names;
              return document.getElementById('name').innerHTML=name;
            }
        }
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- The div where we will inject our map -->
  <div id="info"><h1 id="name"></h1></div>
  <div id="map"></div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: `layers` is not defined anywhere

Comment: I added the rest of the script which does define layers. The error I am getting says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined", which is caused by this line "var name = e.sites[i].names"

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: watershed is not defined`

Comment: Note: watershed is referencing a geojson file, so it makes sense that it is erroring out since you don't have the geojson file to reference. I can edit the code above to remove any references to the watersheds geojson.

Comment: I should also note that when I edit the function to "var name = e.latlng" it works. It has something to do with how I am referencing the circle layer.

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by a classic misconception of JavaScript scopes.

Your `function circleClick` is hoisted out of your `for` loop block; a JS function scope is a parent function block, or the global scope. Same for `var`.

Therefore when you fire the click event, your function tries to access `e.sites`, which is undefined since `e` is the function argument, which value is supplied by Leaflet, which knows nothing about your `sites` variable. You could directly use `sites` instead.

Then it tries to access `sites[i]`, with `i` being the value left after the `for` loop, i.e. `3` since this is the length of your `sites` array. Instead you should simply embed your desired value in your Layer, so that you can easily retrieve it by accessing the Layer which was clicked, which is provided by Leaflet in the click event argument: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#event-sourcetarget

```js
function circleClick(e) {
  const name = e.sourceTarget.options.name;
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;
}

for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
  L.circle(sites[i].location, 200, {
    name: sites[i].names, // you can add arbitrary option to embed your data
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    color: "orange",
    fillColor: "blue"
  }).addTo(layers.CREEK_SITES).on("click", circleClick);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to javascript and leaflet, which was making me hit my head against the wall. I had been trying to figure this out on my own and finally threw in the towel. I can't thank you enough for the help!